# what does *~ mean in glob?

Tags: xcode, mercurial, glob

What is the meaning of `*~` in glob syntax? For example, in a sample `.hgignore` file:

```
syntax: glob

.DS_Store
*.swp
*~.nib
```

what is difference between a `*~.nib` and `*.nib` ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*~` means files end with `~`, mostly used as temporary backup files by IDEs and text editors.